# Write a function that returns a stack, that contains all elements smaller than a given number, and in same order?

Tags: c++, recursion, stack

Good day, and thanks in advance.

My problems is as it is said in the title, write a function that receives a stack and a number, and returns a new stack that contains all the elements of the old stack lesser than the given number, and in same order.

The algorithm must be implemented using recursion, and have the lowest possible time and space complexity.

Since I'm no good with recursion yet, I have implemented this the following way:

```
template<typename T>
Stack<T> lesserStack(Stack<T> s, const T& max){

Stack<T> s1;
for(int i = 0; i <= s.numberOfElements() ; i++){
    if(s.top() < max) s1.push(s.top());
    s.pop();
}
s1.reverse();
return s1;
}
```

It works, but it isn't what it should be, and I have no idea how to make it recursive at all :(

Additional info:

Stack implemented as dynamic array, pop function returns the popped element, and top returns the top element. Reverse function reverse the elements in the stack(so as to preserve original order).

Comment: You pop and push one value too much in your loop.

Comment: To make it recursive, have some index parameter that gets decremented/incremented in each successive call. And don't forget the base case (index = 0 for example) to avoid an infinite call loop. Or, if you want to pop the elements you won't even need an index variable.

Comment: Joachim, I thought so too, yet if I remove <= one value isn't inserted.

Comment: In that case you might want to check that `numberOfElements` really returns the number of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this recursively is rather inefficient.  The non-recursive version would look like this:

```
template<typename T>
Stack<T> lesserStack(Stack<T> source, const T& max)
{
    Stack<T> dest;
    while (s.numberOfElements())
    {
        T t = s.top();
        if (t < max)
        {
            dest.push(t);
        }
        s.pop();
    }
    dest.reverse();
    return dest;
}
```

To convert it, you'll remove the loop:

```
template<typename T>
Stack<T> lesserStack(Stack<T> source, Stack<T>& dest, const T& max)
{
    if (source.numberOfElements() == 0)
    {
        return dest; // break out of your recursion
    }

    T t = s.top(); // get the "last" element
    source.pop();
    lesserStack(source, dest, max); // make the recursive call
    if (t < max)
    {
        dest.push(t); // push the last element - this will be done in the correct order
    }
    // no need to reverse the order as the unwinding of the call stack will put them in the reverse order already
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, it is simple, and is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something on the following lines ( I haven't tested it). The idea is to first go down deep into recursion and push the entry after coming back from the recursion.

```
template<typename T>
Stack<T> lesserStack(Stack<T> s, Stack<T> s2, const T& max){

if ( s.size() == 0 )
  return s2;

T top = s.top();
s.pop();
Stack<T> s1 = lesserStack( s, s2, max);
if ( top < max )
  s1.push( top );
 return s1;
}
```

EDIT: Nice to hear that it works. However, I think it can be improved further avoiding unnecessary complications.

It works as your original code, except the following:
Once it takes the top element from the original stack, **it does not immediately push it onto new stack**. Instead, it first pops out the element and calls this function again for the other elements in the stack. This is because you want to preserve the order and to do so, the one that is popped out first from the original stack, needs to be pushed into last in the new stack.

After it has pushed the other items, the control comes back to this function's next line and then it pushes the item.

Comment: It works, yet I have no idea how, can you explain before I mark the answer?

Comment: Is it  this, everytime a recursive call is made, the top value is stored in the runtime stack, and then when we reach the base case, the values are returned and compared to the max value and pushed into an auxiliary stack, and then returned?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and concise explanation, I would select 2 answers if I could, but I can't :(

Comment: @Matsura No problems! Glad it helped.